# Should I await ValueTask<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, valuetask

Which would be a valid implementation of `ValueTask` please?
Cache service returns data either from cache or DB.

```
public async ValueTask<IList<HrEmploymentDataCustom>> GetEmployeesFacts()
{
    try
    {
        var facts = (List<HrEmploymentDataCustom>) _memoryCache.Get("facts");
        return facts ?? await _accountService.GetEmploymentFacts(DetailsRequestType.All, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var tc = new TelemetryClient();
        tc.TrackException(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Would this be: `var employeesFacts = await _cacheService.GetEmployeesFacts();`

or `var employeesFacts = _cacheService.GetEmployeesFacts().Result;`

Little bit confused here.

Comment: always `await` a Task if you can. Blocking with `.Result` is wasteful at best and deadlocks at worst.

Comment: I prefer await, this way you have a better exception (if something's wrong)... .Result wraps all errors in AggregateException

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between await Task<T> and Task<T>.Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287/what-is-the-difference-between-await-taskt-and-taskt-result)

Comment: Yeah, but what in case of Value return, is this smart enough to do not do it async (performance - wise)?

Comment: @Oram No, a ValueTask is similar to a Task but it's not the same

Comment: @sziszu You may want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003779/2141621

Comment: @sziszu yes, thats correct

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know there's a difference. You're right it's not a duplicate, but for the sake of knowing if you want to `await` or `.Result` the answer to that question is useful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Would this be:

```
var employeesFacts = await _cacheService.GetEmployeesFacts();
```

Typically yes.

> or

```
var employeesFacts = _cacheService.GetEmployeesFacts().Result;
```

> Little bit confused here.

NEVER EVER.

Let's unconfuse you.

First: value task is simply a task that is copied by value instead of reference. **Do not use ValueTask unless you know the difference and have a reason to do so driven by an empirical performance study that indicates that regular tasks are a large contributor to collection pressure.  Just use regular tasks almost all the time.**

You don't change how you *use* a task based on whether it was copied by value or by reference. You await tasks, regardless.

You never use `.Result` on a task, regardless of whether it is a value or a reference.  Why?  Because suppose the task is not complete: then `Result` will wait synchronously for its completion. **Suppose the final step of the workflow is currently in the queue of the current thread waiting to be dispatched**. You just put that thread to sleep!  Now the thread is sleeping, waiting for *itself* to wake it up, and so it will sleep forever.  Never use `.Result`. It's the wrong thing to do almost always.

Comment: This is what I thought, so is it worth in the case above to use ValueTask instead of Task?

Comment: @sziszu: **Do an empirical performance study that determines whether tasks are a large contributor to unwanted collection pressure**. If yes, do the same study again using value tasks and see if it makes a difference. **Answer your question by doing science, not by asking strangers on the internet about the performance characteristics of programs they didn't write and have never run**. You wrote your program; test it!

Comment: Using `.Result` or `.Wait()` ( on a Task ) can be used if you know what you are doing ( For example having a working thread working with Tasks and IAsyncEnumerables ). I would say: Never use it unless you have to and you absolutely know what you are doing.