# How to retrieve the Exception of a ValueTask?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

The design of the upcoming C# 8 [`IAsyncEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32640) uses `ValueTask` and `ValueTask<T>` to communicate the potentially synchronous results back to the consumer logic. They both have the `IsFaulted` property, but unlike `Task`, there is no `Exception` property.

Is it even possible to have a `ValueTask` that doesn't hold a normal `Task` and is in the faulted or canceled state?

The `ValueTask<T>.Result`'s documentation indicates calling it on a failed task will rethrow the contained `Exception`. Would the following code make thus sense to extract the `Exception`?

```cs
IAsyncEnumerable<int> asyncSequence = ...

ValueTask<bool> valueTask = asyncSequence.MoveNextAsync();

if (valueTask.IsFaulted) {
    // this has to work in a non-async method
    // there is no reason to block here or use the
    // async keyword
    try {
        var x = valueTask.Result;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // work with the exception
    }
}

ValueTask endTask = asyncSequence.DisposeAsync();

if (endTask.IsFaulted) {
    // there is no ValueTask.Result property
    // so the appoach above can't work
}
```

The non-generic `ValueTask` does not have a `Result` property. How can I extract the `Exception` then?

Generally, I suppose applying `AsTask` could be used for both extractions, however, I'd think it incurs allocation making the use of `ValueTask` questionable in the first place as I understand it.

Comment: Is there a reason your using `.Result` and not `async`/`await`? You do know that (depending on your context) this [can deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: The above is based on your comment `this has to work in a non-async method` This seems to be your underlying issue but it's hard to tell without more context

Comment: It's not a duplicate as I have issues with `ValueTask`. The linked question doesn't even mention `ValueTask`. I've updated the question with a more detailed example code.

Comment: `ValueTask` should work the same as `Task`. The correct solution is to use `async` her, if not then you should `Task.Run(async () => {});` unless your really sure your not going to get deadlock issues. [Any sync call to an async method can deadlock if you don't do this. `ValueTask` or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52425150/542251)

Comment: So, yes, this is mostly covered by that duplicate.

Comment: "Should work the same": probably if you consider working with it via `await` but I can't use `await`. The context, in case it gives more insight, is that I have to work with those `IAsyncEnumerable`s and their `ValueTask`s from a non-async capable environment such as Rx/Reactive Streams where methods are defined non-async hence I can't use "await".

Comment: There's no way to retrieve the exception from an `IValueTaskSource`, so from there I see two ways: either `.AsTask().Exception` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and catch the exception. Surprisingly, `AsTask()` actually make the underlying `IValueTaskSource` throw the exception, catches it, and creates a faulted task from it: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs,172  At first I was puzzled that there isn't a more optimized path, but in the end exceptions are so costly that once you get one you shouldn't care about micro-optimizations anymore

Comment: And I took a shortcut, sorry. I was reacting on `Is it even possible to have a ValueTask that doesn't hold a normal Task and is in the faulted or canceled state`: the answer is yes, if the code that generated the task used `IValueTaskSource`. Then the task will be lazily generated on demand

Comment: Thanks @KevinGosse. Given that `IsFaulted` exists, I'd think `Exception` could also exist and delegate similarly. Maybe I should try and make an enhancement request to the corefx?

Comment: @akarnokd Since IValueTaskSource is something they built for performance I suppose they already considered all that, but there's no harm in asking

Comment: Posted it: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32977

Answer (score 1):

The common way to block until completion of a `Task` or `Task<T>` is by invoking the [`Task.Wait()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait).

If an exception is thrown, it will be a [`System.AggregatedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception). The [`InnerExceptions` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions) will have the collection of exceptions that caused the current exception.

Starting with .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Core 1.0 there's also the [`GetAwaiter()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter) where you can invoke `GetResult()` on it's return value and will throw the first exception in the collection.

**But you should never do that!!!**

You should do this:

```
// this has to work in a non-async method
try {
    var x = await valueTask;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // work with the exception
}
```

`ValueTask` and `ValueTask<T>` are used to avoid heap allocations when, potentially, the result is already available. It doesn't mean that it's safe to block on that task.

Comment: First, I have to work with `ValueTask` where `IsFaulted` is `true` thus I don't have to block for anything. Second [GetAwaiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.getawaiter?view=netcore-2.1#System_Threading_Tasks_ValueTask_1_GetAwaiter) seems to allocate, thus I wouldn't be likely better than using `AsTask`. Third, the extraction should work without `await` as the parent method is not and can't be marked `async`.

Comment: If you can't use `async` stick with `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear but working with `ValueTask` is mandatory. I can't change to `IEnumerable` because it makes no semantic sense for my case and not possible as the API I'm trying to interact with is not defined by me.

Comment: Where are you seeing [GetAwaiter](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs,e1e6145b38914784) allocating?

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing synchronous and asynchronous APIs. Don't be surprised when it deadlocks.

Comment: [`GetAwaiter().OnCompleted()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/ValueTaskAwaiter.cs,5d7634e3d02b9ce0) requires a delegate for which context has to be added, thus it needs allocation. Plus, I still can't get the Exception through that. "shouldn't be mixing" - I'm quite experienced with sync/async code and deadlock is not a concern here. Getting that Exception out is.

Answer (score 1):

The response by the [corefx team](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32977#issuecomment-432261558) indicates this is indeed not possible directly and can't be easily added due to the need to change a companion interface and that would bring complications along.

The workaround suggested, as I guessed originally, to use `AsTask` to get the `Exception`.

```java
IAsyncEnumerable<int> asyncSequence = ...

ValueTask<bool> valueTask = asyncSequence.MoveNextAsync();

if (valueTask.IsFaulted) {
    var ex = valueTask.AsTask().Exception;
    // work with the exception
}

ValueTask endTask = asyncSequence.DisposeAsync();

if (endTask.IsFaulted) {
    var ex = valueTask.AsTask().Exception;
    // work with the exception
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your best bet would be to use a try statement and attempt to catch the exception there and then handle it later...
In regards to the ValueTask that doesn't hold a normal task, I would think that you'd be able to use lambda methods to resolve that.

```
try {
    var x = Task.Run(()=>{ ... });
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // Do something with exception.
}
```

Or whatever the case would be for ValueTask. Considering C# has focused on Async tasks a lot these past builds, it would be safe to say that you would use lambda and event calls.

```
private void foo(ValueTask task) {
        lock (threadObj) {
            var x = Task.Run(()=> { return task.doWork(); }
            if (x == true) {
                // then do other work...
            }
            else {
                // handle 'exception'...
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me. The starting point is that I have a `ValueTask` returned to me by some 3rd party method. Also what "lambdas" and "event calls" are you referring in respect to `ValueTask`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make much sense. But in essence lambdas are methods encased in parenthesis and brackets. ie foo(object sender, EventArgs e) equates to (s,e)=>{...} and event calls are utilizing events and invoking them. ie someEvent?.Invoke((s,e)=>{...}) This example uses lambads and an event call to invoke a method as a parameter... This kind of programming is typically used in System.Linq. Therefore, what I'm saying is that as soon as you have that valueTask utilize it in a thread-safe context, which can allow you to catch unwanted actions expressed by the program.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with lambdas or creating tasks. I already have a `ValueTask` from somewhere out of my control and have to get the `Exception` out of it.