# Can non-asynchronous execution paths return synchronous results in an "async" method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Consider the following method:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetNameOrDefaultAsync(string name)
{
    if (name.IsNullOrDefault())
    {
        return await GetDefaultAsync();
    }

    return name;
}
```

When `name` is provided, no awaiting will occur in the method execution, yet this method will compile correctly.

However, this method will produce the build warning shown below:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetDefaultAsync()
{
    return "foobar";
}
```

`[CS1998] This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.`

Why is it that `GetNameOrDefaultAsync` can return without ever awaiting, and not result in a compiler warning, but `GetDefaultAsync` must await in order to compile?

Would it be an improvement to do the following?:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetNameOrDefaultAsync(string name)
{
    if (name.IsNullOrDefault())
    {
        return await GetDefaultAsync();
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(name);
}
```

Here we would have no execution paths that don't `await` something.

Comment: Its not a compile error, its just a warning that you might have done something you didn't intend. It is OK to never await an async call, like for a fire-and-forget operation if that is what you really intend.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for that clarification.  I updated the question to specify it's a warning, not error.  Regarding not awaiting, I wouldn't consider this a fire-and-forget operation, because we do care about the string result, and we would await while consuming `GetNameOrDefaultAsync`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is it that `GetNameOrDefault` can return without ever awaiting, and not result in a compiler warning

Because there are execution paths that do use `await`, and to be able to use `await` the method needs to be `async`.

On the other hand, if there are *no* paths that use `await`, the `async` keyword is clearly superfluous, hence the warning.

> Would it be an improvement to do the following?
> `return await Task.FromResult(name);`

No, `Task.FromResult` simply wraps `name` in a `Task` object, which is in a completed state, meaning the `await` unwraps it again immediately.

This allocates a `Task` unnecessarily, and achieves nothing.

---

As an aside, if `name.IsNullOrDefault()` is almost always `false`, i.e. using `await` is the exception not the rule, you could reduce allocations by using `ValueTask` instead: [Why would one use Task<T> over ValueTask<T> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000520/why-would-one-use-taskt-over-valuetaskt-in-c)