# Propagating ValueTask to callers

Tags: c#, async-await, task, valuetask

Say I have a method signature like this:

`public async ValueTask<int> GetSomeValueAsync(int number);`

Internally it may make an async HTTP call but it caches the result so next time it is called with the same `number` it can return the value from cache without the async call. Thus it returns a `ValueTask` as this avoids the overhead of creating a `Task` for the synchronous path of execution.

My question is, the caller of this method, if it makes no other async calls, should the signature be a `Task` or should `ValueTask` be propagated all the way up the call stack?

E.g. should it be this:

```
public async Task<int> CallingMethodAsync(int number)
{
   return await GetSomeValueAsync(number) + 1;
}
```

Or should it be:

```
public async ValueTask<int> CallingMethodAsync(int number)
{
   return await GetSomeValueAsync(number) + 1;
}
```

(examples above are simplified to illustrate the point)

For clarity, this question is not about whether `GetSomeValueAsync()` should return `ValueTask` or `Task`. I understand there are situations for both but take it as such that this evaluation has been made the outcome of that has correctly determined it should be `ValueTask`. The essence of the question is, should the caller of this method propagate up `ValueTask` in it's signature if it itself has no other async method call. Hopefully this clarification explains why the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000520/why-would-one-use-taskt-over-valuetaskt-in-c), does not answer it.

Comment: _should the signature be a Task_ - to convert a ValueTask to a Task you need to call [AsTask{}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.astask?view=net-7.0)..

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you handling the case when the `GetSomeValueAsync` is called by two (or more) execution flows concurrently? Are you doing multiple concurrent async HTTP calls and cache the result of the first (or the last) of them, or you prevent concurrency by using some sophisticated keyed async mutex mechanism?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would one use Task<T> over ValueTask<T> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000520/why-would-one-use-taskt-over-valuetaskt-in-c)

Comment: A counter-argument in favour of `ValueTask` - https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html

Comment: Take a look to [Understanding the Whys, Whats, and Whens of ValueTask](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/), I found it very userfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `GetSomeValueAsync` is expected to complete synchronously most of the time, and the `CallingMethodAsync` doesn't `await` anything else other than the `GetSomeValueAsync`, and also your goal is to minimize the memory allocations, then the [`ValueTask<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1) is preferable.

```
public async ValueTask<int> CallingMethodAsync(int number)
{
   return await GetSomeValueAsync(number) + 1;
}
```

That's because when a `ValueTask<TResult>` is already completed upon creation, it wraps internally a `TResult`, not a `Task<TResult>`, so it doesn't allocate anything. On the contrary if you return a `Task<TResult>`, a new object will always have to be created, unless it happens to be one of the few type+value combinations that are internally cached by the .NET runtime itself, like a `Task<int>` with a value between -1 and 9 (see the internal static [`TaskCache`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskCache.cs) class).

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MDQ0Xh).

In my PC running on .NET 7 Release mode it outputs:

```
CallingMethodAsyncValueTask: 0 bytes per operation
CallingMethodAsyncTask: 74 bytes per operation
```

Comment: I suppose equally you could cache the `Task<T>` in the first place yourself rather than just the values, which is essentially what `TaskCache` is doing. Then no allocation even with `Task`.

Comment: @Charlieface sure, that's the idea behind the [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once "Enforce an async method to be called once") class. But caching a list of `Task<TResult>`s should always be more expensive (memory-wise) than caching a list of unwrapped `TResult`s. A `Task<TResult>` contains a bunch of internal fields, that track the completion status of the task, `Exception` information etc.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

`ValueTask<T>` was introduced for perfromance-critical scenarios when reducing allocations has a significant impact. If you have such scenario - you need to explicitly test you concrete setup on your concrete hardware if using `ValueTask` gives actual benefits (consider using something like [`BenchmarkDotNet`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)).

Assuming cache misses a relatively rare then `ValueTask` should be preferable. Though still I would recommend to run few benchmarks based on cache misses rates and used number ranges estimates.

Details:

First let's start with [the docs](https://confluence.kaspersky.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=OMS&title=OnBoarding%20KORM%20B):

> As such, the default choice for any asynchronous method should be to return a `Task` or `Task<TResult>`.  **Only if performance analysis proves it worthwhile should a `ValueTask<TResult>` be used instead of a `Task<TResult>`**

And:

> There are tradeoffs to using a `ValueTask<TResult>` instead of a `Task<TResult>`. For example, while a `ValueTask<TResult>` can help avoid an allocation in the case where the successful result is available synchronously, it also contains multiple fields, whereas a `Task<TResult>` as a reference type is a single field. This means that returning a `ValueTask<TResult>` from a method results in copying more data. It also means, that if a method that returns a `ValueTask<TResult>` is awaited within an async method, the state machine for that async method will be larger, because it must store a struct containing multiple fields instead of a single reference.

> **For uses other than consuming the result of an asynchronous operation using await, `ValueTask<TResult>` can lead to a more convoluted programming model that requires more allocations**. For example, consider a method that could return either a `Task<TResult>` with a cached task as a common result or a `ValueTask<TResult>`. If the consumer of the result wants to use it as a `Task<TResult>` in a method like `WhenAll` or `WhenAny`, the `ValueTask<TResult>` must first be converted to a `Task<TResult>` using `AsTask`, leading to an allocation that would have been avoided if a cached `Task<TResult>` had been used in the first place.

Lets perform a simple check for allocations:

```
ValueTask<int> GetSomeValueAsync(int number) => ValueTask.FromResult(number);
async Task<int> CallingMethodAsyncTask(int number) => await GetSomeValueAsync(number) + 1;
async ValueTask<int> CallingMethodAsyncValueTask(int number) => await GetSomeValueAsync(number) + 1;

await CallingMethodAsyncTask(1);
await CallingMethodAsyncValueTask(1);
var totalAllocatedBytes = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes();
var iters = 10_000;
for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
{
    await CallingMethodAsyncTask(i);
}

Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(CallingMethodAsyncTask)}: {GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes() - totalAllocatedBytes}.");
totalAllocatedBytes = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
{
    await CallingMethodAsyncValueTask(i);
}

Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(CallingMethodAsyncValueTask)}: {GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes() - totalAllocatedBytes}.");
```

Which gives in release mode "on my machine":

```
CallingMethodAsyncTask: 718784.
CallingMethodAsyncValueTask: 0.
```

But if you change the `GetSomeValueAsync` to something like:

```
async ValueTask<int> GetSomeValueAsync(int number)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    return number;
}
```

Which gives in my setup:

```
CallingMethodAsyncTask: 2413488.
CallingMethodAsyncValueTask: 2475256.
```

i.e. `ValueTask` was less efficient in terms of allocations for completely async scenario.

Notes:

- using `GetSomeValueAsync` with values in `-1` to `9` range can remove allocations for `Task` option due to internal [`TaskCache`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskCache.cs) (runtime implementation depended)
- There is also an alternative to docs point of view: [prefer `ValueTask` to `Task`, always; and don't await twice](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html)

Comment: I think that the `await Task.Yield();` is not relevant with the scenario described by the OP. The `GetSomeValueAsync` is supposed to return synchronously most of the time.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it is to show the variability in the analysis i.e. that concrete cases need to be tested. We don't know actual rate of cache misses, so I think it is worth to mention.

Comment: Well, assuming a 100% cache miss ratio is pretty pessimistic to say the least! This question is not a general discussion about reference  tasks vs value tasks. The context is caching, and AFAIK the general expectation about caching is that most cache requests will be hits, not misses. Otherwise why would you want a cache anyway?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, I agree but when it comes to perfromance I personally prefer to mention such things. Yes, the source of ineffectiveness would be elsewhere (i.e. needless/wrong cache) but I have seen one such cases when totally useless cache was introduced without any actual tests for it effectiveness =)