# why does `boost::lower_bound` take its argument by value?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-range

The implementation of `boost::lower_bound` (found [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/lower_bound.html)) in Range 2.0 takes its argument by value.

Why is this?  `std::lower_bound` takes its argument by const ref - see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Comment: It relies on the compiler to eliminate unnecessary copies, it seems.

Comment: Bug report? Seems like an easy mistake to make.

Comment: @user14717 will do.  The library is at least five years old though (probably older) so I was expecting that there was an implementation reason.  Will update the question if I hear back

Comment: Added an issue [here](https://github.com/boostorg/range/issues/90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed [by this issue](https://github.com/boostorg/range/pull/95).

There may be historical reasons for taking the argument by value.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234682/390557) about function objects passed by value to standard algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

While it is difficult to know for sure the reason for this, there are two things to keep in mind:

- The general reason for passing by value is when you end up making a copy in the function. Also, passing by value can potentially invoke the move constructor on prvalues/xvalues and the copy constructor on lvalues.
- In the recent versions of the boost library `boost::lower_bound` uses `std::lower_bound` in its implementation. Boost 1.59 has the following implementation for the overloads of `boost::lower_bound` mentioned in your link:

```
    template< class ForwardRange, class Value >
    inline BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_iterator<const ForwardRange>::type
    lower_bound( const ForwardRange& rng, Value val )
    {
        BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( ForwardRangeConcept<const ForwardRange> ));
        return std::lower_bound(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng), val);
    }

    template< range_return_value re, class ForwardRange, class Value >
    inline BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_return<const ForwardRange,re>::type
    lower_bound( const ForwardRange& rng, Value val )
    {
        BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( ForwardRangeConcept<const ForwardRange> ));
        return range_return<const ForwardRange,re>::
            pack(std::lower_bound(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng), val),
                 rng);
    }
```

Comment: Range algorithms were introduced in version [1.43](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/upgrade/upgrade_from_1_42.html).  I looked in the [1.43 implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.43.0/) and they use `std::lower_bound` also

Comment: @wreckgar23: So, the second point is not relevant here. Let's see if someone else can provide a more complete answer for this.